# How to connect my Oculus Quest 2 headset which is 5 Ghz when Windows won’t allow me to create a 5Ghz hotspot?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-hotspot

I’ve been trying to connect my Oculus Quest 2 headset to my PC and I bought a 5ghz Wi-Fi card for it but Windows doesn’t allow me to create a 5 Ghz Wi-Fi hotspot if my router doesn't support it which it sadly doesn’t.

I was hoping if there was a workaround for this as I have no way of making a 5 Ghz network at all.

Comment: Your question is not phrased very clearly. It is not clear what you are asking or what you have done. Use the EDIT button to rephrase your question, perhaps beginning with adding punctuation to turn this into a complete paragraph with a few more sentences.

Comment: Your router has doesn’t need to support it.  Your PC must have a WiFi device and you can enable the Hotspot.  However, you also need Internet connection, and you cannot use the same adapter to do that

Comment: I have used an Ethernet adapter and then created an Hotspot with a WiFi Adapter

Comment: Could you clarify: How is your computer connected to the Internet (Ethernet etc)?